# Draw an oval across lines using css

Tags: css

I am trying to draw an oval across lines but I can only do it across some words.

In html& css,

```
Hello world, <br>
it's time to <br>
have a <span class="oval">...break...</span>

.cover-circle {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #92efe6;
}
```

This renders like the following.

[image]

I'd like to make that oval across the lines, bigger like this.

[image]

How can I get that in css only, possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using pseudo elements like this:

```css
.oval {
    position: relative;
}

.oval:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #92efe6;
    opacity: 0.2;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p>before <span class="oval">word</span> after</p>
```